# Python: how to print a variable inside a defined function separately?

Tags: python, function, printing

I want to know how to print a variable inside a function, with python, for example:

```
import math
def number():
    print
    number_enters = input("Please enter the number: ")
    square_roots = math.sqrt(number_enters)
    print square_roots
```

But how can I print the square_roots separately, like print it at the end of the program(after other functions) for example:

```
import math
def number():
    print
    number_enters = input("Please enter the number: ")
    square_roots = math.sqrt(number_enters)
    print square_roots

def bla_bla():
    .....
    .....

.......
.......
print square_roots
```

I hope that make sense, please help me out, how can I print square_roots after all of that?

Comment: use `return square_roots` and capture it another variable

Comment: welcome to SO. be more precise.

Comment: No, it does not make much sense. Anyway, you need to return the value, probably store it somewhere and print it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `print square_roots` with `return square_roots` in the function. This will allow you to use the variable later.

```
def number():
    print
    number_enters = input("Please enter the number: ")
    square_roots = math.sqrt(number_enters)
    return square_roots
```

Then you can store the result in a variable and then print it.

```
square_root = number()
.....
.....
print square_root
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the result from the function in a list for instance and store it in a variable. Later on use this variable to print the square roots at the end of the program. I also don't understand why do you have square root*s* when there is a single (non-negative)square root for each non-negative number(assuming you are using real numbers) and you always compute a single result.